# Custom UITableViewCell with XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I looked around and there are many examples on how to do this, but I am still not getting it.

I have a list where I am listing journal entries which I want to display a title, date created and few other things. I want to use an XIB to design a cell, so UX designer can modify it and pixel push it.

So, this is how i setup the xib:
[image]

Then I made a class that this xib cell points to and I added two properties to it:

```
@property (atomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* titleLabel;
@property (atomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* dateLabel;
```

I want to be able to set these when I create these cells.

In the view that has the list table I do this:
In -(void) viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DreamListTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DreamListCell"];
```

And in - (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath I do this:

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"DreamListCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The problem is that the app crashes if I setup IBOutlets in the cell xib, because I guess the owner is really nil when it is initialized, but I am actually not sure. How could I modify those two properties if I can't connect them in interface builder? What should I do differently?

Also, I am not using storyboards. I am using this as a guide: [Chapter 21. Table Views and Collection Views](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells)

I apologize for sort of duplicate question, I am just not getting it. Halp!

Edit:
Outlet screenshot:
[image]

Edit #2:
If I remove outlet connections in the cell xib i see this:
[image]

Comment: Did you bind your custom class to the cell in IB? You also need to specify that custom class and not `UITableViewCell` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I cast 'cell' to my custom cell class later on, but it crashes before that code is executed. I set file owner to and the root view in the xib to point to my custom cell class :(

Comment: Where does it crash exactly and what's the exception says?

Comment: exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fdb02c55cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key titleLabel.'

Comment: It crashes on the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier call. And I am pretty sure the code inside the if statement never gets executed. There is always a cell.

Comment: Add screenshot showing outlets for your cell in IB

Comment: That code never got executed, so I just removed it. It was left over from another attempt. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Every time I've gotten the "not key value coding compliant" crash, it's because I've deleted something from the layout but there's still a reference to it somewhere. Check the file's owner for broken outlets (warning triangles).

Comment: If i remove outlet connections it works, once I add them back it crashes again. It does seem to be very similar to what you are saying, that's why I think the owner is null.

Comment: Is the above screenshot of outlet connections for `File's Owner`, or for the `DreamListTableViewCell`?

Comment: Aha! I would hug you if you were here. I set File's Owner outlets, not the DreamListTableViewCell. I changed that and now it all works! Thanks

Comment: My answer came a bit too late, sorry about that @pbasdf

Comment: @AndrisZalitis no problem.  Just glad SpaceBear got a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use File's Owner to set the relationships to IBOutlets. Change the class of the cell and use that instead (might be tricky to make the connections on some Xcode versions, but is doable).